# Cannot see past relationships in before_relationship_add hook

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

For some reason when executing $bean->relation->getBeans() inside before_relationship_add hook it shows old AND new relationship.

I just want to see the relationships that were there BEFORE..

I tried to extract it from $bean and $arguments, but can't seem to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see what new record was added by checking **$arguments['related_module']** and **$arguments['related_id']**.

So if we can identify what is the new record, we can determine what the old records were there prior to relationship add..

Example: we have 3 records with IDs 1,2 and 3 and the latest ID that was added is 3 (**$arguments['related_id']**), that means that IDs 1 and 2 were there before relationship was added.

This is kind of backwards and was hoping that before_relationship_ad

Technically speaking we can even do this in the after_relationship_add hook